# Tricky SQL - Select non-adjacent numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

Given this data on SQL Server 2005:

```
SectionID Name  
1         Dan  
2         Dan  
4         Dan  
5         Dan  
2         Tom  
7         Tom  
9         Tom  
10        Tom
```

How would I select records where the sectionID must be +-2 or more from another section for the same name.

The result would be:

```
1 Dan  
4 Dan  
2 Tom  
7 Tom  
9 Tom
```

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Hmm, you say "1 Dan" is in the results and therefore "2 Dan" is not, but why is it not that "2 Dan" is in the results and therefore "1 Dan" is not? I think you assume some order here, which SQL actually does not do. What do you actually want to achieve?

Comment: @wilth, SQL can recognizes relational operators such as < and there is nothing in relational algebra that will prohibit against using properties of such operations on the attributes; it is only if you assign meaning to arbitrary order of the records that you commit cardinal error. You do raise a valid point however, that the operator is not known, but I would say that the record with the lesser ID should be kept.

Comment: @Daniel, what would you return if you had also (3, Dan) in the starting table? Would you return records (1, Dan) and (3, Dan) or only  the first? Is the only condition really that the difference between the selected ids should be greater than 1 (or there are additional conditions)? If that is the only condition, what do you want to do in case of sequence such as: 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11, 12? (it has two solutions, one starting with 5 has 4 elements in the answer, but if you start with 6 you can select 5 elements); how to distinguish?

Comment: Yes I see what you mean and for the data, it is not important what order, only as long as it follows the rule. It can even return different results each time for the same data, it does not matter.

If (3,Dan) was included it could return (1,Dan)(3,Dan) or (2,Dan)(4,Dan) - both are solutions for me.

Comment: @Daniel; if that is so then take a much closer look at the solution you accepted -  in case of 1, 2, 3, 4 it will return only 1; now if in your data it will never happen that you have more then 2 sequential ids, then all is fine (but try to mention such details next time you write a question :) - if you will have more sequential ids then things will break.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable a
WHERE NOT EXISTS
  (SELECT *
  FROM mytable b
  WHERE a.Name = b.Name
  AND a.SectionID = b.SectionID + 1)
```

Comment: +1 Straight-forward and correct solution. A composite index on `(SectionID, Name)` will be greatly beneficial to this query.

Comment: so if you had data:
`1 Tom
2 Tom
3 Tom
4 Tom`
you would get zero records back. Which I suspect is not correct.

Comment: @ninesided, not really - the query returns all the records from table a where for the sectionid there is no record in the same table with sectionid that is less by one (so in your counter example 1 Tom would be returned).

Comment: @ninesided - how so? can you provide a case when it does not work or works contrary to what was requested?

Comment: my understanding of the question as stated was that it should return all SectionID's that are +/-2 of other records with the same Name. That would imply that for my example the correct result would be "1 Tom", "3 Tom" (or maybe "2 Tom", "4 Tom" depending on the ordering).

Comment: Anthony's solution works! I was overthinking this problem. I tried to break it too with different sorts and it's still solid.

SELECT *  
FROM (select top 100 percent * from #tmp order by NewID()) a  
WHERE NOT EXISTS  
  (SELECT *  
  FROM (select top 100 percent * from #tmp order by NewID()) b  
  WHERE a.Name = b.Name  
  AND a.SectionID = b.SectionID + 1)

Comment: @Daniel, I don't understand how this solves your problem. Given "1 Tom", "2 Tom", "3 Tom", Anthony's solution will give a result of "1 Tom" whereas your question indicates the correct solution would be "1 Tom", "3 Tom". Can you clarify this for me please?

Comment: @ninesided - yes that is correct, but as long as it's +-2 or more, it won't break my application. this is more of a very strange bit of business logic than it is an sql riddle. i should have given more detail at first.

does your partition solution solve this for sequential problem, thereby including the maximum number of records? i couldn't get it to work, i'll look at it again. thanks for your good thoughts.

Comment: @daniel, partition is mine and sorry if it does not work, i tested it on postgres; it does not return strict maximum, but it returns more records then the above (i could check for a maximum if you are interested, it might be possible with straight sql); also since it was not mentioned earlier - this kind of task might be better served at client side or as stored procedure, but i guess you know that.

Answer (score 0):

Here's LEFT JOIN variant of Anthony's answer (removes consecutive id's from the results)

```
SELECT a.*
FROM mytable a 
     LEFT JOIN mytable b ON a.Name = b.Name AND a.SectionID = b.SectionID + 1
WHERE b.SectionID IS NULL
```

EDIT: Since there is another interpretation of the question (simply getting results where id's are more than 1 number apart) here is another attempt at an answer:

```
WITH alternate AS (
SELECT sectionid,
       name,
       EXISTS(SELECT a.sectionid 
              FROM mytable b 
              WHERE a.name = b.name AND 
                    (a.sectionid = b.sectionid-1 or a.sectionid = b.sectionid+1)) as has_neighbour,
       row_number() OVER (PARTITION by a.name ORDER BY a.name, a.sectionid) as row_no
FROM mytable a
)
SELECT sectionid, name 
FROM alternate
WHERE row_no % 2 = 1 OR NOT(has_neighbour) 
ORDER BY name, sectionid;
```

gives:

```
 sectionid | name 
-----------+------
         1 | Dan
         4 | Dan
         2 | Tom
         7 | Tom
         9 | Tom
```

Logic: if a record has neighbors with same name and id+/-1 then every odd row is taken, if it has no such neighbors then it gets the row regardless if it is even or odd.

As stated in the comment the condition is ambiguous - on start of each new sequence you might start with odd or even rows and the criteria will still be satisfied with different results (even with different number of results).

Comment: Different, but still has the same issue that @ninesided mentioned.

Comment: Bad idea since SQL server will not be able to convert this to an antijoin.

Comment: @PaulG, can you explain the issue; I asked for more details on ninesided comment under Anthony's answer but none were provided (as far as i can see both queries return the requested data)
@erikkallen, I agree it would not, but the performance should be tested, the NOT EXISTS of correlated subquery performance is not obviously superior to LEFT JOIN performance, even with such high selectivity.

Comment: My understanding of the original question was that any row with an Id +/-2 from another Id with the same name should be returned. Therefore if your data was 1-Tom, 2-Tom, 3-Tom you should expect 1-Tom and 3-Tom to be returned (given that 3 is +/- 2 away from 1)

Comment: @PaulG, ah I see your logic. mine went into "+-2 or more from another **section**"; where I presume section to be non-interrupted sequence. Better go back to OP to clarify.